# How do I disable `-Werror` only when compiling as a library?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have

```
ghc-options:
- -Wall
- -Werror
```

in my `package.yaml` and it builds fine for GHC 8.6.

But when using the project in a GHC 9 codebase, it errors because of an unnessessary MonadFail import.

How can I change the library such that it won't abort compilation when used in other projects?

I have tried

```
ghc-options:
  "$everything": -Wwarn
```

in the downstream (dependent) project, but that doesn't seem to affect it. I expected `-Wwarn` to override the `-Werror` since `$everything` should cover even dependencies.

Comment: There should be some way to perform an `if` inside the cabal file and disable `-Werror` for GHC9 (or maybe disable it only for the specific warning). Another option would be instead to edit your code, assuming `CPP` is on, and write something like `#if GHC >= 9 import Redundant #endif`. See [the docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/phases.html#standard-cpp-macros) for the exact macros you need.

Comment: @chi But I am looking for a way to avoid all warnings in required libraries. I can't know which warnings will be added in future GHC versions... The question is not about this specific MonadFail-related warning (which indeed can be ifdef'd away if I forked the library).

Comment: If the library stack file specifies a hard `-Werror`, I don't think there's anything you can do to avoid that in dependent projects. I don't know if this is possible, but perhaps one could add a flag in the library stack file that disables `-Werror`, and then in the dependent project specify a dependency with that flag (?). Not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, it is bad practice to specify `-Werror` on the library itself. Same goes for other compiler flags, such as optimization for example `-O2`.
Setting `-Wall` on the other hand is definitely good stuff, plus a few other warning flags of top of my head, eg. `-Wincomplete-record-updates`, `-Wincomplete-uni-patterns`, `-Wredundant-constraints`, etc.

If you want to turn build warnings into errors while working on the library or in CI, which is a sensible thing to do, then you can enable it in your

- `stack.yaml`:

```yaml
ghc-options:
  my-library: -Werror
```

- `cabal.project`:

```
package my-library
  ghc-options: -Werror
```

That being said you can turn off `-Werror` for any library downstream by setting `-Wwarn` for that library in the exact same fashion as above, which will override the original flag.

Comment: `-O2` is needed for *some* libraries.

Comment: Needed for sensible performance, sure, but it should never be required for correctness. In the end it is up to the application developer to turn optimizations on or not.

Comment: It's enabled for `containers` right now. I think that's largely because the library has had extensive performance testing with that setting, and no one has done the work necessary to make sure things wouldn't regress horribly without it. The application developer is not in charge of making sure the library sets optimization flags appropriate for that library. They almost certainly have no idea what those are.

Comment: All projects that are build with `stack` or `cabal` will have `-O1` set by default, unless otherwise is specified. That should be enough in almost all cases, even for `containers`. It is only when you compile directly with ghc, that's when you need to specify `-O` in order to get anywhere performance wise.

Comment: I understand a lot of "should"s, but like I said, many people have spent a lot of time measuring `containers` performance with `O2`. If you're willing to do the work to see what changes if we drop to `O1`, then I'll be very happy to make the change if it makes sense.

Comment: @dfeuer I am just reiterating the best practices, I am in no way telling you how to maintain `containers`. You do an amazing job already and I have no interest in getting involved in it ;)